# Weka runtime error

Tags: java, weka, runtimeexception

I am trying to copy the first attribute of my training dataset, and copy the corresponding from Test set for book-keeping purpose.  My code compiles successfully. But I am not able to run it.

I get the following errorwhen run java WekaRF

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/converters/CSVLoader
    at WekaRF.main(WekaRF.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.converters.CSVLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

If I run, java -cp weka-3-8-1/weka.jar WekaRF, I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class WekaRF
```

My code is given below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove;
import weka.core.converters.*;

public class WekaRF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int percent = 60;
        Instances data = null;
        try {
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File("../../rf.csv"));
            data = loader.getDataSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
            }
        int TrainSize = (int) Math.round(data.numInstances() * percent/ 100);
        int TestSize = data.numInstances() - TrainSize;

        Instances Train = new Instances(data, 0, TrainSize);
        Instances Test = new Instances(data, TrainSize, TestSize);
        System.out.println(Test.attribute(0).name());
        Remove remove = new Remove();
        String[] options = new String[2];
        options[0] = "-R";
        options[1] = "1";
        remove.setOptions(options);
        remove.setInputFormat(data2);
        Test = Filter.useFilter(Test, remove);
        Train.setClassIndex(Train.numAttributes() - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classpath does not include current directory so java didn't see your `WekaRF` class.
Try to use `java -cp .;weka-3-8-1/weka.jar WekaRF` instead.
Notice dot at the start of `-cp` argument. It denotes current directory.

Upd: Character used to separate individual class path entries is operation system-depended. Windows uses `;` and most other systems use `:`. The actual path separator can be retrieved by querying [java.io.File::pathSeparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) field.

Comment: You are correct, path separator is system-depended. Windows use `;` and most other systems use `:`.